# How can I play Avoid the Noid on Windows 7?

Tags: pc, backwards-compatibility, dos, avoid-the-noid

I have some pretty fond memories of a game called Avoid The Noid. It was some promotional thing from Dominos pizza and was actually a lot of fun.

After I dug up my original disk and pulled the files from my USB floppy, I got this message when I tried to run it: "The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running."

I tried compatability mode, but nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoid_the_Noid), Avoid the Noid was released for DOS and the Commodore 64. I'm assuming you've got the DOS version here, but if this is the case, you'll probably have to use something like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) to run it.

The [DOSBox compatibility list](http://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?showID=946&letter=A) says that Avoid the Noid should work fine.

Comment: Whoa - that's great! Thanks for the help, that did the trick.