# How can I get past Level 24?

Tags: avoid-the-noid

Now that I've finally got this old classic going (thanks to [Brant](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11613/how-can-i-play-avoid-the-noid-on-windows-7/11615#11615)!), I'm stuck exactly where I left off. A quick search turned up no walkthroughs or guides (no surprise!). So, I'm hoping you can help again.

I'm stuck at Level 24. This is *reaaaally* frustrating. There's a door, and for the life of me, I can't find another key. Any thoughts on where I can find another key? I swear, I checked every non-exploding payphone.

Comment: I've never played this before, but I was curious what it was about and found someone who plays it all the way through:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30Oe3k0sfXc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JustcallmeDrago's comment, I was able to study the you tube [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30Oe3k0sfXc) and beat it!

The secret is to get the *extra* key on Level 6. I never thought to check back that far!